# Keep task stack when opening singleInstance activity from recent apps screen

Tags: android, android-activity, single-instance, launchmode, android-recents

My application contains multiple activities, the main activity (A) is in launchMode singleTop, every over activities are in singleInstance mode.

I've choose singleInstance for preventing illimited navigation
if i navigate like this : A -> B -> C -> B -> C -> B -> C
The back action will do: C -> B -> A

It works as expected.

Problem : If i navigate A -> B then i open app recents screen, click on my application, activity b is displayed (ok) but if I go back the application exits and returns to android home (the activity is not destroyed, I can always open B since recent apps screen)

Why does task history not retain if I open the application from the recent applications menu?

```
<activity
        android:name="A"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:launchMode="singleTop"
        android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.app.default_searchable"
            android:value=".SearchResultsActivity" />
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
        android:name="B"
        android:label="B"
        android:launchMode="singleInstance"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
        android:name="C"
        android:label="C"
        android:launchMode="singleInstance"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    </activity>
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: This cannot possibly "work as expected". Setting `launchMode="singleInstance"` is useless if you do not also set `taskAffinity`. Please post how you transition from A->B->C->B->C. If you just call `startActivity()` for each transition, you will definitely have multiple instances of B and C in your task.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If a singleInstance Activity is called, a new task would be created. Through `dumpsys`, we could find two tasks, but only one task shows in Task Manager. This could be a system bug. And if Activity B set `taskAffinity`, there could be two tasks in Task Manager.

Since you start singleInstance B from A, there would be two tasks existed:
Task 1 contains Activity A, while task 2 contains Activity B.

You open the task 2 from the Task Manager which only contains a singleIntance Activity B, so you can not back to Activity A.

It works well when using back button, because

> Regardless of whether an activity starts in a new task or in the same task as the activity that started it, the Back button always takes the user to the previous activity.

You can get this from [Developer Document: Tasks and Back Stack](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/tasks-and-back-stack.html).

I suggest you not to use singleInstace mode if it is really really necessary.

Comment: launch modes `singleInstance` and `singleTask` don't work as documented/expected if `taskAffinity` is not also specified because `taskAffinity` trumps these special launch modes.

Comment: @DavidWasser Yes, and I think this could be a system bug.